# Getting type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Info>' in type cast in flutter unit testing using mockito

Tags: flutter, mockito, flutter-test

I have generated mock class for my store and repository class using @GenerateMocks as below::

```
@GenerateMocks([],customMocks: [

  MockSpec<MyStore>(as: #MockMyStore, returnNullOnMissingStub: true),

  MockSpec<MyRepository>(as: #MockMyRepository, returnNullOnMissingStub: true),

])
```

this has automatically created a test.mocks file for both store and repository class but while writing unit testing I am getting error: **'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future' in type cast.**

The test cases I have written as below:

```
test('call api successfully', () async {

      when(mockStore.calApi()).thenAnswer((realInvocation) => Future.value());
      expect(await store.calApi(), true);
    });
```

//MyStore class

```
class MyStore = _MyStore with _$MyStore;

abstract class _MyStore with Store {
  late MyRepository _repository;

  _MyStore(MyStore repository)
      : this._repository = repository;
Future<bool> callApi() async {
    
        final isInternet = await Util.checkInternetAndShowDialog(context);
    
        if (isInternet) {
    
          final future = _repository.callApi();
    
          var res = await future;
    
          return true;
    
        }
    
    return false;
    
        }
}
```

Can any one help me to resolve this issue, why I am receiving 'Null' subtype error and pass the test cases in flutter. I shall be thankful for this.

Comment: can you post the code in some good way. I can't understand a thing by looking at this for now

Comment: @AsimJawad let me know if you understand now. I am using mockito for unit testing.